# Survey Monkey - use custom variable in design and embedding these in email too

Tags: email, html-email, surveymonkey

When we use custom variables in the first question of a Survey and then we choose to embed the first Question in an email, these variables disappear when we receive the email.

Problem is that in the design we have to write our variables like this

```
{{ contact.custom1 }}
```

And in the email like this

```
[CustomData1]
```

When we receive the email, the {{ contact.custom1 }} just disappeared from the question...
Is there a way to make this work?

The design:

[image]

And then the incoming email

[image]

Comment: Does `custom1` actually have a value for that contact? (https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Custom-Data) If so then I think this is more of a question for SurveyMonkey support, I'd shoot them an email, may be a bug.

Comment: Yes it has a value for sure. When I click on the link in the email and then get on the survey on surveymonkey.com itself, the value is filled in the question. Also in the mail, the value with square brackets gets filled in correctly but not the embedded one with curly brackets inside the first question (which is embedded with the tag [FirstQuestion] in my email html). I am awaiting answer from a developer. I did send them a mail via their support form.